# Can't access DynamoDB at all from Lambda using Node.JS - Timeout

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am trying to access a DynamoDB table from AWS Lambda. I am following the AWS node.js documentation for "[Reading and Writing A Single Item in DynamoDB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-table-read-write.html)".

Here is what I'm doing:

1. Go to the AWS Lambda console and click "Create Function".
2. Enter a function name. Leave the runtime as "Node.js 6.10"
3. Select "Create new role from template", enter a role name, and choose the "Simple Microservice permission" template. Click "Create function".
4. Paste in the following code for the handler function (based on the example in the above referenced documentation):

   ```
   exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => 
   {
      console.log('Load the AWS SDK for Node.js');
      var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
      console.log('Set the region');
      AWS.config.update({region: 'REGION'});

      console.log('Create the DynamoDB service object');
      var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-10-08'});
      console.log('Done Creating the DynamoDB service object');

      callback(null, 'Hello from Lambda');
   };
   ```

   (Yes, I realize that this code doesn't actually access any DynamoDB tables, but I'm just trying to demonstrate that I can't even get as far as initializing the SDK.)
5. Click "Save"
6. Click "Test" at the top of the screen, and keep the default test event. Click "Test" to run the test.

When the test runs, I get the following error:

> { "errorMessage": "2017-12-12T23:37:49.578Z
>   74ef4b3f-df95-11e7-a4cd-b55e8170a5e5 Task timed out after 3.00
>   seconds" }

Here is the log output:

> START RequestId: 74ef4b3f-df95-11e7-a4cd-b55e8170a5e5 Version: $LATEST
>   2017-12-12T23:37:46.579Z  74ef4b3f-df95-11e7-a4cd-b55e8170a5e5    Load the
>   AWS SDK for Node.js END RequestId:
>   74ef4b3f-df95-11e7-a4cd-b55e8170a5e5 REPORT RequestId:
>   74ef4b3f-df95-11e7-a4cd-b55e8170a5e5  Duration: 3001.29 ms    Billed
>   Duration: 3000 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 32 MB
>   2017-12-12T23:37:49.578Z 74ef4b3f-df95-11e7-a4cd-b55e8170a5e5 Task
>   timed out after 3.00 seconds

Note that the only one of my explicit log entries that actually gets logged is "Load the AWS SDK for Node.js", which means that the execution of my function does not get past the following line:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
```

What am I doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Give it more time to ensure that it isn't a simple case of a not-quite-fast-enough warmup, and/or give it more CPU power -- which is done by giving it more memory.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - Thanks, that was it! I increased the timeout, and it started working.